# hard drive HDD filesystem not available in bios to choose as boot option, only hard drive USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, uefi

After messing with Efi partition sda1 (100mb fat32 esp boot) with some efi/grub data on it I'm getting some issues with get back my Asus laptop's hard drive to work. If there's no USB attached with live OS it boots straight to bios and in bios the hard drive is detected but no any boot option with OS installed on hard drive (windows 10 and ubuntu).
Below photos from my current bios options:
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc4YC.jpg)
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lXfV6.jpg)
[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SXHxt.jpg)
[4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o2RTN.jpg)
[5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gD3mB.jpg)

in HDD option tab there's only USB drive options and the filesystem to choose if I want to add new entry. In Ubuntu live mode by adding new entries via efibootmgr command I get this:

```
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L "Ubuntu" -l \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi
sudo efibootmgr -c -d /dev/sda -p 1 -L "Windows" -l \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi
```

and output:

```
efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0009
Timeout: 1 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0009,0007,0008
Boot0000* Ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,f874cbe0-f4e9-4972-8fac-6abf2eea49d7,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIubuntushimx64.efi)
Boot0001* Windows   HD(1,GPT,f874cbe0-f4e9-4972-8fac-6abf2eea49d7,0x800,0x32000)/File(EFIMicrosoftBootbootmgfw.efi)
Boot0007* Hard Drive    BBS(HD,,0x0)..GO..NO........i.M.D.O. .U.S.B. .2...0. .5...0.0....................A.............................6..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.M.D.O. .U.S.B. .2...0. .5...0.0........BO
Boot0008* CD/DVD Drive  BBS(CDROM,,0x0)..GO..NO........o.H.L.-.D.T.-.S.T. .D.V.D.R.A.M. .G.U.7.1.N....................A...........................>..Gd-.;.A..MQ..L.Z.K.D.B.J.7.2.F.1.7. .3. . . . . . . . ........BO
Boot0009* UEFI: MDO USB 2.0 5.00    PciRoot(0x0)/Pci(0x1d,0x0)/USB(1,0)/USB(1,0)/HD(1,GPT,1ba7e9d7-5953-4ef3-8b09-f83c1fec0ffe,0x800,0x3d37df)..BO
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

the hard drive is strangely described and attached without any factory info, model, etc....after reboot all these new insertions are gone.
Is there any possibility to attach hard drive to be detected by bios also in boot options? or there's need to reinstall Windows 10 or use other commands in Ubuntu live mode? Now I can only run systems from USB or DVD.
Please let me know if some options are available as I need equipment to back to work. Any suggestions appreciated :-)

Comment: What model Asus? Is drive the newer NVMe type? Have you updated UEFI from Asus? ASUS VivoMini UN45 UEFI update required to see NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2355295

Comment: Hi, the model is from 2014 model line X750JB, UEFI mean Bios flash update? I've tried but as the latest version available on the Asus website is same as installed in my laptop I can't "reflash" it, flash soft won't let me do this.

Comment: Some vendors still call UEFI as BIOS since users know that. It looks like your system has 2 drives. Are they AHCI or RAID? If RAID 0, you cannot change to AHCI without erasing everything. But if RAID 1 you can if you want two drives instead of one.

Comment: i guess it's not the issue, meanwhile I've managed to temporarily get back grub menu...so probably also in bios it would be visible...via grub command prompt: set root=(hd0,x)
set prefix=(hd0,x)
insmod normal
normal
then pin vmlinuz, initrd.img...etc and menu popup but none system loads ;-) i guess there's a mess in partitions and their changed names, some symlinks, paths as I did some operations trying to recover by 'rescatux cd' or 'boot-repair' and both messed my laptop for the worse ;-)...tomorrow will check this out further and do all manually by myself. the best way as usuall ;-)

Comment: Some brands violate UEFI spec and use description as part of boot. You may need a work around and boot the fallback or hard drive entry not ubuntu entry. Sony, HP & others workarounds:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/486752/dual-boot-win-8-ubuntu-loads-only-win/486789#486789  Boot-Repair will now do copy of shimx64.efi to bootx64.efi for fallback boot. But not all systems have UEFI entry to use that.